# Condição *ngIf para aplicar uma classe

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu estou tentando aplicar uma classe quando meu elemento é clicado, porém ele está dentro de dois *ngFor.

Pensei em fazer com array multidimensional mas aparentemente essa não é a forma correta pois está aplicando a classe em vários elementos.

Tentei algo como:

```
<div *ngFor="let tabelaAnuncioContas of sortedData; let a = index">

   <tr *ngFor="let anuncio of tabelaAnuncioContas.data[0].anuncio; let i = index">
       <td><img [class.zoomImg]="zoomImg[a][i] == true" (click)="zoomImg[a][i]= !zoomImg[a][i]" [src]="anuncio.produto.foto_prin_1"></td>
  </tr>

</div>
```

**TS:**

```
zoomImg:[][] = [[]];
```

Quando tem mais de um elemento no array sortedData é retornado:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Quando tem apenas um elemento no array sortedData não é gerado nenhuma mensagem de erro porém ao clicar no elemento todos os elementos aplicam a classe.

Comment: Cheque antes de iterar `*ngIf="!tabelaAnuncioContas.data[0]"`

Comment: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: faça somente para o `!tabelaAnuncioContas`

Comment: Se eu colocar <div *ngIf="!tabelaAnuncioContas.data[0]"> o elemento nao é mostrado

Comment: Somente o !tabelaAnuncioContas não é mostrado minha listagem.

Comment: Quais são os dados compostos por `SortedData` ?